# vlookup next match or skip row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the next match in excel when using Vlookup or Index Match. I cant seem to skip results I already have. I cannot have a helper column because it is a database that is imported from access that I cannot change, and I can't have VB code (mainly because I don't know VB too well and I don't know how to use it in excel). Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

This is just an example. I have a database with hundreds of records from 50 teams that I don't really want to give out

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/947848-lookup-a-value-and-return-multiple-results.html#post3367753

Answer (score 1):

Use this "array formula" in G4

`=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$100,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$100=G$1,ROW(A$2:A$100)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(G$4:G4))),"")`

comfiirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down as far as required and more. When qualifying values run out you get blanks

Adjust ranges as required